# how to pass list type property to controller in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

Model

```
public List<Int32> OrderId { get; set; }
```

View

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-click="modal-show" href="@Url.Action("PrintInvoice", "list", new {@id = Model.OrderId })" title="Print Tax Invoice">Print Invoice</a>
```

Controller

```
public action list(list<int> id)
{
    return view()
}
public action test()
 {
   test model=new test();
   model.Orderid=getlist();
    return view(model)
 }
```

how to pass list type value pass to controller ,otherwise please Suggest the method

Comment: You cannot using `Url.Action()`. The url needs to be `../List/PrintInvoice?id=1&id=2&id=3` etc. But why are you doing this?

Comment: When bind item in property then pass into view and pass value to controller

Comment: not pass as static the whole list pass to the controller